# How to make a function return a union of type from a union variable?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to create a new object from a source that is a union of object type.

TypeScript does not manage to infer the typing of the new object as a union.

Any idea how to solve this issue or if it is a limitation of TypeScript?

Here is a quick example to understand the issue:

I could do a switch case or write manually the return type but I want a modular code that does not require changes when adding a new source type.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gVwE4GNoF4oG8BQV9SiQBcUA5AO4DOZeBSEAhgCYRKlZXCPASlko4AOyEQUwAJZCA5mQC+OOVAA+2OviJ9yAMwkAbCLQJQGLNhy48tQhAFsARmwUKcB4FCqJUW+MjRRMLE1+XQMyABoTJlZ2fE5uXlIARgAmORcAegAqPCyoAFEkJDhY6QhgX28AdQlgAAsYBOgGYGQhQnBoCSooXLUoPI1O0gAiahGVKBHQiBGAbj78S0SpwRExSRkJ1RsHNgWBqCU+qS5oqDhtRdxDoZIpmfnFjybSXcckA7ylZWvn4Km4y+BGWWhGa1E4ik0ieh2OAwyODWXCgZQqXjQNXqjSsASgAAoAJQBAB8-Xo5Ta5OMdy0nj8EAAdJpwuoaaDSPTvIzTDFGaC2c4cEjhCiuZjag0mni0ZUJdimkScBJtATxRAsVKrMzOgF0JgyDMyMSbgQMhkCkUSmz1Zqcbx+dKANSYJKKIA) / [Bug report link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54041)

```
type Source = {
    type: 'ws'
    reader: {state: 'connecting'}
} | {
    type: 'file'
    reader: {state: number}
}

let source: Source = {type: 'file', reader:  {state: 12}}

/*
 * Error: getSourceWithState return type is 
 * {
 *   type: "ws" | "file";
 *   state: "connecting" | number;
 * } 
 * instead of
 *  {
 *   type: "file";
 *   state: number;
 * } |
 *  {
 *   type: "ws";
 *   state: "connecting";
 * } 
 */
const getSourceWithState = () => {
    return {
        type: source.type,
        state: source.reader.state
    }
}

const sourceWithState = getSourceWithState()
if (sourceWithState.type === 'file') {
    // Error
    sourceWithState.state += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Typescript does not do "distributive control flow analysis".

As explained by @jcalz in this [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54041#issuecomment-1525648100), the cleanest solution is to do this:

```
interface SourceMap {
    ws: "connecting";
    file: number;
}
type Source<K extends keyof SourceMap = keyof SourceMap> =
    { [P in K]: { type: P, reader: { state: SourceMap[P] } } }[K]

type SourceWithState<K extends keyof SourceMap = keyof SourceMap> =
    { [P in K]: { type: P, state: SourceMap[P] } }[K]

function getWithState<K extends keyof SourceMap>(s: Source<K>): SourceWithState<K> {
    const type: K = s.type;
    const state: SourceMap[K] = s.reader.state;
    return { type, state };
}

let source: Source = { type: 'file', reader: { state: 12 } }

const getSourceWithState = () => getWithState(source);

const sourceWithState = getSourceWithState()
if (sourceWithState.type === 'file') {
    sourceWithState.state += 1 // okay
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQGUD2BXGKCyCADqgN7CqWoDuAzgFyoBESmYYUSE4A5kwNwUqcEABsojMNgC2AI1iCAvsAgBPImiy4UAHgDSqKAA9oYACa1UAayirMcDDjxRCJALzXb9x9pfEAfKhuQpSkqADaAAqo4Kh6ALqMYWoajJEANKgwUAhmsEmotBAI0Ixazq5R8aiKNTXhCcAq6ppOKADqIBAAFujF0PqGJlDmljZ2DuUExEGeEz4VAUEhZBHRsQkFKRKoGYX9O1N%20RFV1ig3xTXDYYFwgbKg8UBCdPX0lUIPGphZz3keufwACgYC10en8AEoym0oK9egd9IFyFRUKwwEVUNtGAYPLQAHTbQSo9GYoofGG%20SoJWYE7K5WD48nQYlUbIQXBgVbbTLMtCKJRNcQQQqwynOWbJFqMADkInEMsy9LyMAKfMYAEYAExnJqkkVPCBHeHvaCzIGQoKBQ0mg4g2GQwTAfWi3y2j6zQ3GroIj4W0AOe1un2mqCElpBNweOViKAyy0oqi0WHu6BMg6oADUHg1wEUQA)

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple returns

```
const getSourceWithState = () => {
    if (source.type === 'file') {
        return {
            type: source.type,
            state: source.reader.state
        }
    } else {
        return {
            type: source.type,
            state: source.reader.state
        }
    }
}
```

(well, you can also define the return type but I guess you don't want that)

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I would like something modular that does not require additional code for any new source type and I can't manage to find a way.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
type SourceType = "ws" | "file"
type SourceReaderState = "connecting" | number;
type Source = {
   type: SourceType,
   reader: {state: SourceReaderState}
}
```

Comment: Hello Haris,
Thanks for your return but this is the typing I already have but don't want.